# como pasar datos de un observable a una variable

Tags: angular

estoy intentando pasar los datos de un observable a una variable en angular

```
token:String;
```

en esta variable de arriba quiero guardar lo que traigo del llamado de la funcion autenticacion

```
 this.auth.autenticacion(this.auth.getToken()).subscribe(data => {
  token=data.data.token
 });
```

para luego simplemente mostrarla en consola, el problema es que me muestra que no trae nada

```
if(token==token){
  console.log("verdadero")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

notamos que tienes una variable tipo string:

```
token:String;
```

y la funcion que trae tus datos:

```
this.auth.autenticacion(this.auth.getToken()).subscribe(data => {
  this.token = data.token
 });
```

suponiendo que traes un valor de objeto llamado *token* en tu variable *data* ese sería el cambio a realizar. Sin embargo subscribe tiene 3 valores, ok, error y complete deberias manejar los otros casos tambien asi por ejemplo:

```
this.auth.autenticacion(this.auth.getToken()).subscribe(
   data => this.token = data.token,
   error => console.log(error),
   complete => console.log(complete) //es opcional
     );
```

Comment: lo que pasa es que yo quiero usar la variable fuera del subsribe para poder hacer una condicion con ella. pero no quiero hacer la condicion dentro del suscribe si no a fuera

Comment: @AlbertoJulioArceEscolar  con el this.token, ya lo tienes para todo el componente. Si lo quieres manejar a nivel global, usa interceptores y guarda el valor del token en localStorage. localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);. Luego desde donde quieras puedes recuperarlo, con o sin interceptores.

Answer (score 0):

Con BehaviorSubject es tanto un Observable como un observador y lo podes llamar o modificar en cualquier  parte del codigo con estos metodos yo lo utilizo para enviar mensajes entre componente tiene multiples utilidades y creo lo podras usar como medio para vincular a tu string con tu observable

```js
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';


token:String;
token$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');
ngOnInit() {
  this.token$.subscribe(m=>console.log('token',m));}


 public escucha(): Observable<string> {
    return this.token$.asObservable();
}
public emite(token: string): void {
    this.token$.next(token);
}
this.auth.autenticacion(this.auth.getToken()).subscribe(data => {
  this.token=data.data.token;
  this.emite(this.token)
 });
```